# Is font.loadAsync necessary for custom fronts in React Native 0.62.2?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, custom-font

I built my project via

```
expo init App
```

and chose the default 'blank' option, so I do not have any iOS or Android directories.

After following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@harshvitra/using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-52ebb3c51454), Expo threw the following error when I initially tried to reload my app:

```
fontFamily "Aileron-Black" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.
```

I noticed that no other tutorials used loadAsync for custom fonts, so I was curious if this method is truly necessary? Moreover, after changing the text within my JavaScript file, I found it surprising that no errors arise and the custom font is displayed properly. Is this a bug or is this an installation issue? If the latter applies, what is the proper way?

**Notes**:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.62.2
- expo: 3.23.1
- OS:  Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 1):

Cache your font before application startup using `expo-font`

Here the code

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appIsReady: false,
  };

 componentDidMount() {
    this.prepareResources()
 }

  prepareResources = async () => {
    await cacheAssets();
    this.setState({ appIsReady: true });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.appIsReady) {
      return <Text>loading...</Text>;
    }

    return <YourApp />;
  }
}

async function cacheAssets() {
  const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
    { "poppins-regular": require("./assets/fonts/regular.ttf") },
    { "poppins-bold": require("./assets/fonts/bold.ttf") },
  ]);

  await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}
```

And now trying adding your custom font family to your Text component.